# Get map image along with visible elements data

Tags: api, dictionary

I can get static map images from map providers like Openstreetmap (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Static_map_images) and Google maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/). I can specify zoom level, and appropriate text labels are displayed in the images; labels of country names, cities, rivers, special buildings, etc.

Now I'm looking for a way to get these images along with data describing the elements of the text labels that are visible in the image (i.e a list of elements, for this particular zoom level, in this particular area).

Would prefer not to detect the text labels using some OCR method (image bitmap analysis).

Do you know of any good way to do it? Perhaps there is some good map api for this? Thanks!